# Date format shows seconds in dropdownlist asp.net

Tags: asp.net, date-format

I have a pretty simple Problem i guess..

In my db i have a Date field Orderdate with Format yyyy-MM-dd

Now i want to make a dropdownlist that Show all distinct orderdates i have in my db but when i test the dropdownlist in my browser it don't take the Format from my SQL db. Instead of yyyy-MM-dd it writes dd.MM.YYYY 00:00:00

Why is it like that and how can i change it? Do i have to present the date from db as a string?

```
<p>
    Datum:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="OrderDate" DataValueField="OrderDate">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EventConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT OrderDate FROM Orders"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `dataTextFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"` in your DropDownList ,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
     runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
     DataTextField="OrderDate" 
     DataValueField="OrderDate" 
     dataTextFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**or**

Code behind ,

```
DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";
```

You can reference about [DateTime Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)  !